# How to use options_from_collection_for_select combined with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby

I want to select an ID from a dropdown that displays the ID - Name options from an Account table.

```
<% f.input :account_id, :as => :select, :collection => options_from_collection_for_select(Account.all, 'id', 'name'), :label=> 'ID' %>
```

When I click the textbox, I hope to see options like
1 - Jones
2 - Jeans
3 - Smith
etc..
but with the current code, it will only be Jones, Jeans, Smith, etc. How can I customize the text_method ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[options_from_collection_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) returns a string of option tags that have been compiled by iterating over the collection and assigning the result of a call to the value_method as the option value and the text_method as the option text.

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Account.all, 'id', 'name')
```

Means you are looping through all the Account records and calling `account.id` as `value_method` and `account.name` as `text_method` for each record. You can't use this helper to archive what you want because expected select option includes the **index number also**

[options_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) suites your need better. Replace `options_from_collection_for_select(...)` part by below code

```
options_for_select(Account.all.each_with_index{ |acc, index| [acc.id, "#{index+1} - #{acc.name}"] })
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> 1. You should move `Account.all.each_with_index{ |acc, index| [acc.id, "#{index+1} - #{acc.name}"] }` into a helper method
> 2. Also you can set the selected value of the selector by passing an `id` as second param of `options_for_select()`

**UPDATE:**

If the prefix number is the record id then `options_from_collection_for_select` can be used. You just need to declare a instance method inside Account model like below:

```
def name_with_id_prefix
  "#{id} - #{name}"
end
```

Then in the view, call the new method instead of `'name'`

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Account.all, 'id', 'name_with_id_prefix')
```

Comment: sorry, I meant the 1 - Jones means Jones' account ID is number 1, not the index. I'm not sure how to map this

Comment: oo nvm I did it using options_for_select(Account.select(:id, :name).map{|e| ["#{e.id} - #{e.name}", e.id]}) thank you very much

Comment: If the prefix number is the record's id you can declared a instance method in Account model that return the string include the record id + name. I have updated my answer.